# Rails 5: Active Storage Link Adds ?local=en

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a products model that has many images via Active Storage

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
 has_many_attached :images
end
```

My products/show view shows the first image as a link to a modal that shows all the other images:

```
- if @product.images.present?
  = link_to image_tag(@product.images.first, class: "img-fluid"), "#", data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#images"}
  / or
  = link_to image_tag(url_for(@product.images.first)), "#", class: "img-fluid", data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#images"}


#images.modal
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content    
      .modal-body
        .carousel-inner
          .carousel-item.active
            = image_tag = @product.images.first, class: 'd-block w-100'

          - @product.images.drop(1).each do |image|
            .carousel-item
              = image_tag image, class: 'd-block w-100'

      a.carousel-control-prev data-slide="prev" href="#image_controls" role="button" 
        span.carousel-control-prev-icon
      a.carousel-control-next data-slide="next" href="#image_controls" role="button" 
        span.carousel-control-next-icon
```

It works well for a few minutes. But somehow, `?locale=en` gets added to the image link from Active Storage after a few minutes so that the image does not show anymore.

```
<img src="/rails/active_storage/blobs/longstring/image_file.jpg">
```

becomes

```
<img src="/rails/active_storage/blobs/longstring/image_file.jpg?locale=en">
```

My routes file:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja/ do
  resources :products
```

How do I prevent rails from adding `locale=en` to the image link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was not the locale, but was something else that was solved by this: https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/rails-5-2-active-storage-and-beyond